# How to copy file from static external folder to resource static folder in spring boot programmatically

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a project in which i am working with spring boot and d3 , I need to move the CSV file from external static folder to resource folder using java NIO move method,
To do that , I need file "fromPath" and "toPath" to move the file , but the problem is I am not able to understand what should be the "toPath" 
src/main/resource/static/data/ this will be the toPath but the problem is i cant give this path as toPath , otherwise while i build and deploy it , this create problem for me as src/main/resource will not exist while build the project.
Can anyone help 
I am using Spring Boot 2.0.0 release

Comment: at what stage do you expect to copy the external file? build or deploy?

Comment: src/main/resource folder does exists while build and deployment. All the resources such as properties are read from it during deployment.

Comment: you can add resources path in `application.properties` and use that property whenever required OR you can get current classpath using system property using `System.getProperty("java.class.path")`.